Restore DBs from higher level version of SQL Server to a lower
I'm trying to restore a Databases from SQL Server 2019 to SQL Server 2017.
The only way that I found in the internet and in the forum was to generate a script.
Unfortunately when the file is large it got an error:

For smaller files it works but for large not.
Can you tell me if there is another way to do that?
The upgrade of SQL Server is not the best option.
I also tried with import/export, attach/detach but nothing works.
Tried with generate scripts method, import/export and attach/detach.

A possible solution to your problem: How do you import a large MS SQL .sql file?.

@Zhorov I know about that CMD command but firstly I have to open the generated script and edit the local path where the DB should be saved on the destination server. Unfortuantely I cannot open the .sql file for edit because it's too large. The SQL CMD directly run the script without possibility to edit it (or I'm not aware if it's even possible).

When you asked your question, you were told "Please make sure to post code and errors as text directly to the question (and not as images), and format them appropriately." Please follow the instructions when posting your questions, as otherwise you are likely to receive down and/or close votes; meaning your question is far less likely to be answered.

you don't have to open the file in SSMS, i think sqlcmd can just execute the file

@siggemannen yes it will execute it but before that I have to open the file and edit some of the lines. That is the problem

How large is the file? You can perhaps trying open it in a non-toy editor like notepad++ or sublime

I tried with notepad++ but again cannot be open. It's 35 GB. I have even bigger.

Why are you exporting all the scripts to a single file? If you know it's going to result in a massive text file, then separate the extract into multiple files. Generate Scripts, for example, can easily split into one file per object.

I'm not aware if it can be separated in more than one file.. Do you know how can be achieved?

What's wrong with the "One script per object" feature?

Yeah, i think most editors won't be able to open less along save a 35 gb file :/

Why are you opening it in an editor? Why not just execute the file using using tools such as sqlcmd?

@ThomA ok for the "One script per object" but now when I have to import in the destination SQL server, which of the multiple generated files I have to choose?

"which of the multiple generated files I have to choose?" The one(s) you need.

they are about 150 files for each object.. The one that I need is the one that ends on ".database.sql". Is that correct?

If you only want to create the database with no objects and no data, then yes... But then if that's all you need why did you create scripts for every object..? That's like saying "I need to buy some cheese, so I'm going to put everything in the dairy isle in my shopping cart" and then when you get to the check out, search for that one block of cheese you actually wanted.

@ThomA I'm creating script for each object because I cannot edit the . SQL file if it's too big.  I have to edit the content(the path where the restore DB will be stored) of the SQL file.

You may try exporting .bacpac file from source and import to target db. If the database is quite big you may fall into out of memory when using SSMS and the operation will get terminated. You can use the sqlpackage utility to do the same with parameter Storage= File. Refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage-export?view=sql-server-ver16
